# Selectively ignoring Ctrl+C / SIGINT

Tags: bash, signal

I have the following `bash` compound command:

```
while true ; do slow-command-one ; slow-command-two ; slow-command-three ; done
```

What happens:

- When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> at any point, the entire command is aborted.

What I want to happen:

- When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> during execution of `slow-command-two`, `slow-command-two` should be aborted, and execution should continue with `slow-command-three`.
- When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> at any other time, the entire command should be aborted (as now).

How do I get this to happen?

Comment: Ctrl-C is `SIGINT`.

Comment: Ta, have edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `trap` command for that. Catch `SIGINT` with it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  does not hurt your command execution. Then reset trap to default settings.

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  slow-command-one;
  trap "echo Proceeding to command three" SIGINT;
  slow-command-two;
  trap - SIGINT;
  slow-command-three;
done
```